# Docker-compose with a React-Service always chooses PORT 3000 even though Package.json has ""start": "set PORT=3500 && react-scripts start""

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm running a few Micro Services using docker-compose :

**Dockerfile :**

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

**docker-compose.yaml :**

```
version: '3'
services:
  lb:
    image: dockercloud/haproxy
    links:
      - api-gateway
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    restart: on-failure

  api-gateway:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: development.Dockerfile
    image: microservices-workshop/api-gateway:dev
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=api-gateway.app.com
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./api-gateway:/app/src

  delivery-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: development.Dockerfile
    image: microservices-workshop/delivery-service:dev
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./delivery-service:/app/src

  order-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: development.Dockerfile
    image: microservices-workshop/order-service:dev
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./order-service:/app/src

  restaurants-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: development.Dockerfile
    image: microservices-workshop/restaurants-service:dev
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./restaurants-service:/app/src

  react-service:
    build:
      context: ./react-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /node_modules
      - ./react-service:/src
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 3500:3500
```

**And here is Package.JSON of the React app :**

```
{
  "name": "reactservice",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=3500 && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

However when I hit : `docker-compose up` , I get :

```
Compiled successfully!
react-service_1        |
react-service_1        | You can now view reactservice in the browser.
react-service_1        |
react-service_1        |   Local:            http://localhost:3000
react-service_1        |   On Your Network:  http://172.20.0.4:3000
react-service_1        |
react-service_1        | Note that the development build is not optimized.
react-service_1        | To create a production build, use npm run build.
react-service_1        |
```

...even though I've set the port to `3500`.

Where did I go wrong ?

**BTW , I work under WINDOWS 10**

Comment: Did you rebuild the image after changing the port?
Try `docker-compose build` and then `docker-compose up`

Comment: @Nikolay: I've tried it , still the same result...

Comment: hmm very strange, if you have node installed on your pc you can try to run `npm run start` directly and check the port.. at least to know whether the issue is from the docker or not